# Can one java class/file be part of more than one package?

Tags: java, class, package

I'm a relative beginner to Java, and I was just learning about packages and access restrictions, so I was wondering if it was possible to have one Java class belong to more than one package. 
I don't mean sub-packages.

Comment: No. If it were possible, what'd be the purpose of that?

Comment: A file can belong to a single package, and all of a class lives in a single file. The JLS is your friend.

Comment: No. But that's going to be solved in [Java 9](https://labs.consol.de/development/2017/02/13/getting-started-with-java9-modules.html) by the module system. What's your use-case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can have a same class with same content in two different packages but then when you use these 2 classes in another Java class then you would have to be very specific (absolute package name) when using either of the class.

Let me give an example ...

Here is class `Testing` which has exactly same members but are defined in two different packages i.e. `com.overflow.stack` and `com.stack.overflow`.

When they are used in an another class `Test`, you have to import both of them and use absolute package name for at least one of the `Testing` class so that Java compiler understand which instance is which class (alternatively you can use absolute package name for both the Testing class instances).

--

```
package com.overflow.stack;
public class Testing {
    public void whoAmI() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

--

```
package com.stack.overflow;
public class Testing {
    public void whoAmI() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

--

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import com.overflow.stack.Testing;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // not using absolute package name
        Testing test1 = new Testing();
        test1.whoAmI();

        // must use absolute package name if want to use Testing class
        // from different package then above.
        com.stack.overflow.Testing test2 = new com.stack.overflow.Testing();
        test2.whoAmI();
    }
}
```

Sample Run:

```
com.overflow.stack.Testing
com.stack.overflow.Testing
```

That being said, if you or your team or organization is the author of this class then you should avoid having copies of classes in different packages as it will lead to redundant code duplication and will be very confusing for the consumers of these classes. Also it is highly possible that these copies will get out of sync and possibly lead to `RuntimeException` which are difficult to debug and can crash the application.

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot be.

But however there can be classes with same name in different packages, but no two similarly named classes in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put package declaration twice in the same class.
The package statement must be the first line in the source file. There can be only one package statement in each source file, and it applies to all types in the file.

However you can define same classes - same name and even same implementation in two  packages but package name must be different.

Read more about packages [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a class with the same name in other packages. 
It's not best practice of designing an application.